# Getting error while configuring the jackson mapper object for SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to serialize a domain object I created called User to a json file.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    users.add(user1);
    users.add(user2);
    users.add(user3);

mapper.writeValue(file, users);
```

Above works fine and writes the data in an unfriendly one liner manner to a file. 
I want to prettify it when writing to the file. So I came across `SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT`, but this is not compiling for me for some reason.

```
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
```

The error I get in the eclipse compiler is as follows:

> The method configure(SerializationConfig.Feature, boolean) in the type
>   ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments
>   (SerializationFeature, boolean)

What's going on here? Am I missing something obvious? Its not working as shown in documentation. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that two versions of `Jackson` is on your classpath 1.x and 2.x and you are mixing the two. Your `ObjectMapper` seems to be from 1.x and you are trying to pass a `SerializationFeature` from the 2.x version.

So you either have to use a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` (2.x) or have to pass a `SerializationConfig.Feature` to the method `configure`.

See [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonUpgradeFrom19To20) for the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You might have Object Mapper from both `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` and `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper`

```
//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper can be used like this,
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

//org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMappe can be used like this,
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
```

Hope this will be helpful.